# is there a way to make my bot joins a voice channel even it is empty

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so what I am trying to reach is that I want when someone adds the bot to the server he can run a command with voice channel ID [!join 9562xxxxxxxxxxxxx] and it joins the channel and played the music even the voice channel is empty, because I am controlling the music throw the code I made, so it is something like a radio station.

I hope I did a great job explaining the problem and I am really a beginner programmer.

**node v12.22.10**

**discord.js v12.5.3**

What I was doing is getting a server id and channel id and putting them in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using discord.js v12 anymore as it uses an old version of the Discord API which will deprecate soon. If you still want to use v12, you should do the following thing:

```js
let args = message.content.substring(1).split(" "); // Array of the arguments

switch(args[0].toLowerCase()){
   case 'join':
      if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send(`Please enter a voice channel id`);
      if(!Number(args[1])) return message.channel.send(`Please enter a valid voice channel id`);
      const vc = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[1]);
      if(!vc) return message.channel.send(`This voice channel does not exist`);
      if(typeof vc.join !== 'function') return message.channel.send(`The channel is not a voice channel`);
      vc.join().then(connection => {
           const dispatcher = connection.play('Your Song URL');
      }).catch(err => {
         message.channel.send(`There was an error while connecting to the voice channel`);
      });
      break;
}
```

Comment: Hey man thank you for your response, well all things work perfectly but the thing is no sound and I got the error same one mentioned in the code.
---------------------
what I did:  https://prnt.sc/kqtwhkydKyoH

Comment: You're using a YouTube video to play which is unplayable. You should be using a package like [yt-stream](https://npmjs.com/package/yt-stream) or [play-dl](https://npmjs.com/package/play-dl) to play a YouTube video.

Comment: this is what I did and I got the same problem unfortunately all works fine no errors except playing the audio. -- https://pastebin.pl/view/e076d8a5